# How do I convert from PowerPoint to Word?

Tags: conversion, microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, file-conversion

I'm  using PowerPoint 2007 and  need  to convert a PowerPoint document  to a Word  document.

I can't convert or copy directly from PowerPoint because my native language is Georgian and the computer can't simply detect it.

Comment: See this....http://presentationsoft.about.com/od/powerpointinbusiness/ss/ppt_to_word.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to Export PowerPoint Text Contents to Word?](http://www.lytebyte.com/2009/08/07/how-to-export-powerpoint-text-contents-to-word/).

This article demonstrates two methods:

1. Save PowerPoint Outline in Word
2. Creating PowerPoint Handouts in Word (Send to Word)

For the Handouts method, which generates better-styled documents, a very detailed article is :
[How to Send PowerPoint Handout to Word for Printing](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Send_PowerPoint_Handout_to_Word_for_Printing_29188344)